# Inconsistent behaviour in recursion in Permutation

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a class that does permutation of an array using heaps permutation algorithm but when I print out all the permutation I get all the correct permutation, add the items to a list and then print the list, I get the same item repeated. here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
 namespace HeapsPermutation
{
  class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] numbers = new string[4];
        numbers[0] = "a";
        numbers[1] = "b";
        numbers[2] = "c";
        numbers[3] = "d";

        Permutation<string>.permutate(numbers.Length, numbers);

        Console.Read();

    }

}

class Permutation<T>
{
   static List<T[]>  permutated_items = new List<T[]>();
    public static void permutate(int n, params T[] array)
    {

        if (n == 1)
        {
            foreach (T x in array)
            {
                Console.Write(x); // gives correct result
            }
            Console.WriteLine(); 
            permutated_items.Add(array); // does no add correct result
        }

        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            {
                permutate(n - 1, array);
                if (n % 2 == 0)
                {
                    swap(ref array[i], ref array[n - 1]);
                }
                else
                {
                    swap(ref array[0], ref array[n - 1]);
                }
            }
            permutate(n - 1, array);
        }
    }

    private static void swap(ref T x, ref T y)
    {
        T temp = x;
        x = y;
        y = temp;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? I want to be able to copy-paste-and-run your code in a console app and see the issue you're facing.

Comment: by adding `static` to `List<T[]> permutated_items = new List<T[]>();` (fixing compilation issue) and executing with the arguments you've provided it correctly prints permutations.

Comment: @Enigmativity I just added a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: @PawełŁukasik yea, it prints out all the permutation but I want it to be added to the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array are reference types! So you operate on the same object you change items in all of them. Clone the array before adding it to the list.

```
permutated_items.Add((T[])array.Clone());
```